# Displaying all stylesheet parameters In XSLT

Tags: xslt, saxon

Does Saxonica allow you to discover the names of the stylesheet parameters? I'd like to get all the parameters passed to transform:transform from XQL, not knowing in advance what the parameters are which have been passed.

Comment: Which version and edition of Saxon? https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltExecutable.html#getGlobalParameters-- exists in the Java s9api.

Comment: I'm running 9.9 PE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what parameters are declared in the stylesheet, the s9api API gives you `XsltExecutable.getGlobalParameters()`.

However you seem to be doing the opposite: rather than the application discovering what parameters the stylesheet wants, you're wanting the stylesheet to discover what parameters the application has supplied.

I would suggest that you declare a single parameter called say "options" or "params" whose value is a map. You can then discover what key-value-pairs are contained in the supplied map using `map:keys()`.